# Вывести нужные слова

Tags: c

Эта прога считает количество заданной буквы в словах, и выводит то слово, в котором больше всего этой буквы. Но если таких слов несколько, то выводится только первое слово. Мне нужно, чтобы выводились все слова, в которых наибольшие количество одинаковой заданной буквы.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
int n;
do
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    int input_word[40];
    int result_word[40];
    int povtor_lit = 0, max_povtor_lit = 0;
    int lit, sym = ' ', i = 0, q = 0;
    int arr[40];

    printf("\n\tВведіть літеру - ");
    lit = getchar();
    while (getchar() != '\n') {}

    printf("\n\tВведіть речення - ");
    while (sym != '\n') {
        i = 0;
        povtor_lit = 0;
        while ((sym = getchar()) != ' ' && sym != '\n') {
            input_word[i] = sym;
            if (sym == lit || sym + 32 == lit) {
                povtor_lit++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (povtor_lit > max_povtor_lit) {
            max_povtor_lit = povtor_lit;
            q = 0;
            for (; q < i; q++) {
                result_word[q] = input_word[q];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tЛітера %c повторюється %d разів у словах - ", lit, max_povtor_lit);
    for (i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        printf("%c", result_word[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    printf("\n\tПродовжити? 1/0\t", &n);
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    scanf_s("%*c");
} while (n == 1);
```

}

Comment: Результат надо сохранять в массив строк

Comment: Я знаю, но я не знаю, как это правильно сделать. Я пытался, но не получилось

Comment: Судя по коду у вас  и не должно получаться много результирующих слов, а всего одно в связи с этим условием **if( povtor_lit > max_povtor_lit)**. Надо ввести критерий по которому будет формироваться массив слов с нужным результатом

Comment: Короче, надо сохранять не в массив строк, а в ассоциативный массив. То есть для текущей буквы (которая является ключом в ас.массиве) проверять текущее значение и если в нем меньшее количество данных букв чем в новом слове, то менять на новое.

Comment: Давай, если не сложно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если максимум обновлен, сбрасываете счётчик слов в 0.

Если он повторён или обновлён, записываем текущее слово в массив и увеличиваем счётчик

```
  if (povtor_lit >= max_povtor_lit) {
     if (povtor_lit > max_povtor_lit) {
          q = 0;
          max_povtor_lit = povtor_lit;
     } 
     result_word[q++] = input_word[i];
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Набросок кода на С++, для того чтобы показать саму идею. На С реализация будет чуть длиннее и сложнее. 
Где-то вне main сделаем такую структуру:

```
struct MostString
{
   std::string s;
   int charCount;  // количество данных букв
}
//....

int main()
{
    //...

    std::map<char, MostString> words;
    do
    {
        char ch = getchar();
        while(sym != '\n')
        {
            int counter = 0; 
            while(...)
            {
                // Считаем буквы в строке TheString
            }
            if( counter > words[ch].charCount )
            {
                words[ch] = {TheString, counter};
            }
        }
    } while(...);
    }
}

Как-то так.
```

Comment: Вопрос-то на С, так что будет чуть сложнее.

Comment: У меня на Си, так что это мне не подошло

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Ну да, сложнее. Поэтому и набросок. Мэп надо делать самому ))

Comment: Не может быть для этого столько строк. У меня есть подобное всего лишь на пару строк. Я пробовал сделать по примеру, но не получилось(

Comment: @Asmund поэтому и набросок, так быстрее показать идею. Вам надо самому реализовать ассоциативный массив